# libisabelle with existing Isabelle installation

Tags: isabelle

I want to use [libisabelle](http://lars.hupel.info/libisabelle/) to invoke Isabelle from Scala. However, by default (i.e., using the invocation as described in the [tutorial](http://lars.hupel.info/libisabelle/tutorial.html)), libisabelle will download a fresh Isabelle installation.

I wish to use an existing (read-only) Isabelle configuration instead. I tried the following:

```
val path = "/opt/Isabelle2016-1"
val setup = Setup.detect(Platform.genericPlatform(new File(path).toPath), Version.Stable("2016-1")).right.get
val resources = Resources.dumpIsabelleResources().right.get
val environment = Await.result(setup.makeEnvironment(resources), Duration.Inf)
val config = Configuration.simple("Example")
System.build(environment,config)
val system = System.create(environment,config)
```

I am not sure whether this is how I am supposed to set things up, but in any case, it does not work:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/Isabelle2016-1/.lock
```

So libisabelle wants to write to the Isabelle installation. I want the code to work even with a read-only installation.

How can I get libisabelle to work in the above situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Setup.detect` will attempt to lock the installation such that no two processes can write into them at the same time.

Using a `genericPlatform` probably doesn't do what you think, because the path you pass there will be used for *everything* that libisabelle obtains from or writes to disk, including resources.

Luckily, instantiation a `Setup` manually is quite simple:

```
val setup = Setup(
  Paths.get("/opt/Isabelle2016-1"),
  Platform.guess.get,
  Version.Stable("2016-1")
)
```

With that incantation, you'll use the global installation in `/opt/Isabelle2016-1`, but nothing is written there. `$ISABELLE_HOME_USER` etc. will point towards `~/.local/share/libisabelle` on Linux.

Comment: It works for me with a minor fix: `info.hupel.isabelle.Platform.guess.get` instead of `Platform.guess().get`. (`Platform` is shadowed by `java.lang.Platform` and the `()` tries to invoke the return value of `guess`)

Comment: Thanks, I've incorporated the `guess()` → `guess` change. The `Platform` problem should go away with a wildcard import from `info.hupel.isabelle._`.

Comment: "The Platform problem should go away with a wildcard import from `info.hupel.isabelle._`." Indeed, it does. Strange that I had problems earlier, since I had that import in my source...